# Adding the billing card to the Heroku account and cons/pros of using dynos

Tags: heroku

Since I am not very familiar with Heroku I need opinion of a specialists like you. I got two questions to which I cannot find an answers on the web.

1. Heroku tempts with the 450 dynos if I add the billing card.
   **Is that secure to add it?**
2. Will they take the money from my account without my permission? If for instance I have used all the dynos, would they take the money from my account to add some dynos?
3. Do dynos last for long? How many users can use my site if I got 1000 dynos?
   I tried to understand the answers from the another questions here in stack, but I could not understand them.

**Please do not use the technical language, try to answer these questions as simply as you can (for me and users who will read it).**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very vague question, so I'll do my best to answer it clearly.

1. Adding your credit card to Heroku is perfectly safe. They are a legitimate company.
2. Heroku will automatically charge your credit card at the end of the month if you go OVER their free tier, meaning you use more than 450 dyno hours across your Heroku account, or if you provision paid addon services.
3. Dynos last forever, until you remove them. Heroku allows you to add dynos, remove them, etc., all instantly.

You also asked how many users your site can support if you have 1,000 dynos: this is equivalent to asking how many users your site can support if you have 1000 web servers. This is dependent on many factors: what does your site do? How was your site built? Etc.. In general, most webapps on Heroku only require 1 dyno to run indefinitely.

Comment: If I add a credit card the heroku will give me 450 dynos + 550 dynos free, so I will have 1000 dynos. I got a question to second sentence. Is there a way to prevent heroku from charging my account automatically?

Comment: @Charllie heroku won't give you 1000 dynos, its 1000 **dyno hours**. Heroku allows you to have at the maximum of [100 dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#dyno-scale) for an application

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @Charllie a dyno is a web server. Heroku charges you by the HOUR, not by the dyno. So if you have 2 dynos running for 1 hour each, that means you would use a total of 2 dyno hours. If you have 1 dyno running for 1 day, that means you would have used 24 dyno hours. Does that make sense?

Comment: Am I right? Simply saying, I give to Heroku all credentials of my card (even cvv number!). And those honest guys will pay for me any sum if I exceed limits. The only way I see it, they will use my credentials in bank payment gateway by entering my credentials there. It means that I violate the main bank instruction - not to give my card credentials to anybody??? Because the onsite form where they ask you to enter CVV is not bank gateway page. Sh.t, am I right?

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm not sure what you are implying here. Heroku is a hosting company. You pay them to run your web applications. They are not going to pay you anything. Heroku also (like all other companies) requires you to pay them using some sort of card. In order to pay them, they have to have your card number. I'm not sure what you are implying.

Comment: Bank says: do not give your card information to anyone, even to bank employees. The only place where you can enter those data (including 3 digits secret number) is page of bank gateway.Those are special pages that designed in a special way with specific information. Heroku asks all of your data on their own page, this is not even a page, popup window.This is not payment page, because you have (in my case) free plan, which is not require any money transfers.That means that they keep all of your credit card data on their servers. Otherwise, how can they get your money when you exceed the limits?

Comment: @rdegges Is there a way where I can avoid my bank acc from being automatically charged when I exceed those 1000 dyno hours? Like I'm getting an application error when I exceed 450 dyno hours (without adding the billing card). Similarly, would I get the same error when I exceed 1000 dyno hours (after adding the billing card) or they just charge automatically from my acc?

Comment: @Kishan there isn't any way to do that from what I can see. But, you will get Heroku email notifications letting you know when you are approaching your limit.